# Why are RecyclerViewAdapter DummyContent elements and methods static?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

When you create a new Fragment(List) using Android Studio, it creates a RecyclerViewAdapter which is initialized from a List of DummyItem elements, which are instantiated in the DummyContent class.

The DummyContent class has a static final list of DummyItems; subsequently the methods to populate the list are also static.

Is it necessary or recommended for some reason that this list be static instead of dynamic?  With the data source being static, it seems like there is no opportunity to reuse the RecyclerView for other items.  Do I need to create a new Fragment, ViewAdapter+ViewHolder and Content+ContentItem every time I want to show a list of something?

```
public class DummyContent
{
    public static final List<DummyItem> ITEMS = new ArrayList<DummyItem>();
    public static class DummyItem
    {
        public final String id;
```

RecyclerViewAdapter

```
public class MyItemRecyclerViewAdapter extends 
RecyclerView.Adapter<MyItemRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder>
{
    private final List<DummyItem> mValues;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When you create a new Fragment(List) using Android Studio, it creates a RecyclerViewAdapter which is initialized from a List of DummyItem elements, which are instantiated in the DummyContent class.

That is sample code, designed to illustrate how to use `RecyclerView`.

Personally, I almost never bother with those wizards, as I spend as much time getting rid of stuff as I would have in just creating what I wanted from scratch.

> Is it necessary or recommended for some reason that this list be static instead of dynamic?

It is not necessary that the data used in a `RecyclerView` be referenced by a `static` field.

> Do I need to create a new Fragment, ViewAdapter+ViewHolder and Content+ContentItem every time I want to show a list of something?

Most likely you will want at least some of those, such as:

- A Java class that represents the distinct attributes of your different model objects (e.g., a bookseller app would not use a `Book` class to represent an author, because the properties of a `Book`, such as page count and publisher, do not apply to an author)
- A `ViewHolder` that knows how to take a model object (e.g., `Book`) and pour its contents into views for an individual row in your list
- An `Adapter` that has access to your collection of model objects (e.g., `List<Book>`) to display in the list and knows about the `ViewHolder`(s) needed to render that list

Whether you need a new fragment depends entirely upon the navigation flow of your app.